# Unable to update the minecraft native launcher - Mac OSX 10.11.4 (El Capitan)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

I keep getting an error when trying to install the newest Minecraft launcher which says, "unable to update the minecraft native launcher".

Anybody know what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try to reinstall Minecraft(delete it from the Applications folder, then run the installer).

If it didn't work, do you have avast?(BUG URL: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCL-3959)

In Avast, you'll need to disable both the File and Web Shields found under Preferences > Shields. Once both shields are disabled, you should be able to get the newest version of the launcher.

Comment: The Avast thing is probably what's happening. Thank you!

Comment: @SunnyS. No problem. If it works, can you mark my answer as accepted? It helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

On Macs, the JAR launcher works better than the APP version

But you have to have Java installed, otherwise it won't work.

[Choose the Jar version here](https://minecraft.net/en/download/alternative)